Tracking Entity changes in .NET 8 + EF. Custom vs Temporal Tables
In my .NET 8 project, I've implemented entity changes tracking for auditing purposes by adding custom code to the SaveChanges method of the context. Here's the code snippet:
  if (entry.Entity is IActionsTracked actionOnEntity && entry.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
   {
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
     {
      DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never,
     };

     string details = JsonSerializer.Serialize((object)actionOnEntity, options);
                
     var trackAction = new ActionsTracker
     {
      ActionDone = entry.State.ToString(),
      Date = DateTime.UtcNow,
      UserId = _userAccessor.UserId,
      Details = details
      };
      ActionsTracker.Add(trackAction);
  };

...
This code serializes the modified entity into a string each time it implements the IActionsTracked interface and gets modified, storing the modification details.
Now, I'm considering using Temporal Tables for this auditing feature. My question is: would Temporal Tables be a better approach for this scenario? Is the potential impact on performance significant enough to warrant sticking with the custom code instead of utilizing Temporal Table SQL feature?
Thank you for your insights!

I've been researching the same question and talking to our Database Administrators the concern of performance is minimal, temporal tables are quite efficient and when you take into account the massive pros of being able to report and query specific changes while support is so minimal compared to updating the changeTracker logic each time the entity/database changes, it makes a lot of sense to go with Temporal tables.
